# require_once () gave me error

Tags: php, iis

```
require_once('/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php'); was in the correct place
```

but the error says:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\xxx\download.php on line 5
```

Line 5 point to require_once. I am not sure why it gave error, when on local development it doesn't complain.

**EDIT #2**
Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Unable to create file C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs/csv/brochure-list.csv because No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mta2013\downbrochure.php on line 161

code:

```
$filename= ABSPATH. 'csv/list.csv';
            $isNew = (file_exists($filename) || is_file($filename)) ? false : true ;
            touch($filename); //Sets access and modification time of file and  If the file does not exist, Create it.
            $fp = fopen($filename, 'a+');
            forceHeader($columns,$filename);

            fputcsv($fp, $formData);
            fclose($fp);
```

I might be overlooking something here. but I added ABSPATH and it doesn't resolve the error.

**EDIT #3**

Alright I resolved it because the directory wasn't set to permission or 'recognized'. thanks for the help.

Comment: putting recaptcha in your root folder is not a good move. place it somewhere under your document root.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - no recaptcha was in wp-content/themes/new-theme

Comment: but requiring '/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php' means it's an absolute path, and you refer to your machine's root folder, C:\ in this case.

Comment: @safarov - tested and it still gave same error :(

Comment: Try this: `require_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');`, If it works, I'll explain if it doesn't, do put the error returned.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog - no just now i tested again it doesn't work. same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
require_once('/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
```

You are actually directing PHP to the root folder(which in windows is `C:\`) while you actually want to move to the following folder:

```
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs\
```

I guessed that your server folder is httpdocs, and PHP by-default takes it as its base directory. Hence, you don't need to use the `/recaptcha`. Therefore,

```
require_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
```

Works great.

Comment: This time, you are traversing folders like this: `C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs/csv/brochure-list.csv` where you change from `\ ` to `/`

Comment: so I have to change from / to \? or is there a way to get the correct path?

Comment: Why do you wish to use Absolute path?

Comment: no i am trying to get the path correct so I use ABSPATH to see what happened. Of course I got same error. it can't be as simple as first problem?

Comment: thank you for your help. I found out that the directory wasn't set to permission. :)

Answer (score 2):

THis means you dont have permission to include that file in php. Look here [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)
Move that library inside `vhost` folder and use or change `open_basedir` configuration